# setbackground not working in constructor of Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm playing with JFrames but when I try to set the background color of a JFrame it's not working. As far as I know you need to set the background color on the contentpane of the JFrame. in that case I don't see why this won't work.

```
class drawCircles extends JFrame{
int [][] s;
Container c;
public drawCircles(int [][]circleArray){
    super();
    setSize(400, 400);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    s=circleArray;
    show();
}
```

EDIT: yes I did override the paint()

```
public void paint (Graphics g){
    int width=this.getHeight()/10;
    int start=width;
    int endY=this.getHeight()-width;
    int endX=this.getWidth()-width;

    for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
        g.drawLine(i*width, start, i*width, endY);
        //g.drawLine(start, i*width, endX, i*width);

    }
    //g.drawRect(start, start, width*s.length,width*s.length);

    for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<s.length; j++){
            switch(s[i][j]){
            case 0: g.setColor(new Color(252, 177, 177));break;
            case 1: g.setColor(new Color(250, 165, 165));break;
            case 2: g.setColor(new Color(242, 156, 156));break;
            case 3: g.setColor(new Color(224, 133, 133));break;
            case 4: g.setColor(new Color(208, 117, 117));break;
            case 5: g.setColor(new Color(199, 107, 107));break;
            case 6: g.setColor(new Color(191, 98, 98));break;
            case 7: g.setColor(new Color(181, 88, 88));break;
            case 8: g.setColor(new Color(171, 79, 79));break;
            case 9: g.setColor(new Color(161, 71, 71));break;
            default:g.setColor(Color.white);

            }
            g.fillOval(j*width, i*width, width, width);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you override the `show()` method? If yes, post its contents, if not, use `setVisible(true)`, `show()` is deprecated. Are you adding something to the `JFrame`? Maybe some `JPanel`... If you are, you should set the background to these components too

Comment: Or did you override JFrame's `paint()`? Your question as currently presented is not answerable. Consider giving us more information and code.

Comment: in paint: super.paint(g); (as first line ofc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't override JFrame's paint method. Period.  This is why your current code isn't working as you're not allowing the JFrame's super object to do its requisite painting.

While adding the super's method might well fix your problem:

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);
  //... your code
```

Still you shouldn't do this since paint is responsible for many more things than painting a component including painting child objects and borders.

Better to override paintComponent of a JPanel and be sure to call the `super.paintComponent(...)` method in your override. More important -- read the Java Swing graphics tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft! Now that makes sense. I'll just use a JPanel to set the background color. Thanks for your help. (I need to wait for a few more minutes to accept your answer)

Answer (score 3):

- Custom drawing is done in `paint()`, for Swing JComponents `paintComponent()` instead of `public drawCircles(int [][]circleArray){`
- don't to draw directly to `Top-Level Containers`, put there `JPanel` by override `paintComponent()` and `getPreferredSize(otherwise is there zero dimension)`
- basic is very good described in Oracle tutorial [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mKorbel and for the link. That helps me.

Comment: for important rest of to search in post java + swing + paintComponent, note great code examples are in @HFOE posts